# How to calculate the following integral

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if you could help me to find the following integral:

$$f(u)= \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{e^{-itu}}{{\sqrt {1+t^2}}} \;dt$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Modified Bessel Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1): $2K_0(|u|)$.

Let $t=\sinh(x)$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-itu}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iu\sinh(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(u\sinh(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=2K_0(|u|)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question; I find $K_0(u)$ in math world: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html so   $K_0(|u|)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} cos(ut)/ \sqrt{1+t^2} $ what about $ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} i sin(ut)/ \sqrt{1+t^2}$?

Comment: @May: $\frac{\sin(ut)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ is an odd function of $t$, so the positive and negative reals will cancel.

Comment: I have another question which somehow relates to this one. In this link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html there is a PDF based on modified bessel function. but this PDF is for the case that both mean values are zero. Now I want to find the general formula for PDF of XY with non-zero means. I would appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: @May: the best thing to do is to post a question, showing what you've gotten so far or what you've tried. It is hard to answer a question like that in a comment, and a larger group of people, who might know more about these things, would be able to answer.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I posted it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495773/how-to-calculate-the-following-double-integral