# How to calculate the following double integral

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if you could help me to find the following integral, thank you.

$$f(u)= \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{e^{ -(x-a)^2/2b^2} }{{b\sqrt {2\pi}}} \frac{e^{ -(y-c)^2/2d^2} }{{d\sqrt {2\pi}}} \delta (xy-u)  dx dy$$

where $\delta()$ is [delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) and a, b, c , d are real numbers.

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html) when *a* and *c* are **zero** the answer would be
$$\frac {K_0 (\frac{|u| }{bd})}{ \pi bd}$$

where $K_0()$ is [modified Bessel function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).
Now what if *a* and *c* are not zero?

I simplified it as follows (not sure if it is correct)

$$f(u)=\frac1{2\pi bd} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac 1{|y|} e^{ -(\frac uy-a)^2/2b^2} e^{ -(y-c)^2/2d^2}     dy$$

Comment: So this integrates along the hyperbola $y=u/x$ for non-zero $u$. Are you sure an analytic solution exists? For $u=0$ you are integrating either $x=0$ or $y=0$. You can separate out that case and the integral should split, change variables $z = (x-a)/b$ to get $e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$, which  should give you 1.

Comment: There is a small difference between your expression and the one of the Normal Product Distribution you cite, i.e. in the denominators of the exponents you should take $2b^2$ and $2d^2$ instead of $2b$ and $2d$. Is it just a typo or you want to compute exactly what you wrote?

Comment: @gt6989b Since there is a solution for the case that a and c are zero, it should have a solution.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Thanks a lot! I edited the question.

Comment: just to make it more concrete, how to get rid of $\delta$: substitute $y=u/x$ in the exponentials,then multiply them by $dx/|x|$, and integrate over $x\in\mathbb R$ (not that I know how to do it, bu the integral looks Besselish). Perhaps it's not a smart move to get rid of $\delta$.

Comment: Do you have a proof for the $a=c=0$ case? I think that the knowledge of the right integral representation of $K_\nu$ could unlock the problem...

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano unfortunately I don't. You are right that can help!

Comment: @user8268 using your simplification method, it would be: $$f(u)=\frac1{2bd\pi} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{ -(\frac uy-a)^2/2b^2}  e^{ -(y-c)^2/2d^2}   dy$$

Comment: @May There is $1/|y|$ missing (provided I got it right)

Comment: The original paper by C. Craig (1936), **web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/GaussianProduct1934.pdf**  contains the distribution for non-zero and different means. Just be careful to follow his notation.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thank you.

Comment: $\Large\delta\left(xy\ -\ u\right) = {\delta\left(y\ -\ u/x\right) \over \left\vert x \right\vert}$ .

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56998), it is shown that when composing the dirac delta with $g(x)$, we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\,\delta(g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathcal{S}}\frac{f(x)}{|\nabla g(x)|}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)
$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is the surface on which $g(x)=0$ and $\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)$ is standard surface measure on $\mathcal{S}$.

In the given integral, $\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)$ is arclength and
$$
|\nabla g(x)|=|(y,x)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
If we parameterize the curve $xy=u$ by $y=u/x$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)
&=\sqrt{1+y'^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{x^4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the integral becomes
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ -(x-a)^2/2b^2} }{{b\sqrt {2\pi}}} \frac{e^{ -(u/x-c)^2/2d^2} }{{d\sqrt {2\pi}}}\sqrt{1+u^2/x^4}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^2+u^2/x^2}}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ -(x-a)^2/2b^2} }{{b\sqrt {2\pi}}} \frac{e^{ -(u/x-c)^2/2d^2} }{{d\sqrt {2\pi}}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|}
\end{align}
$$
which is what you got.

Comment: $\large \left\vert x\right\vert \sim 0\ ?$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{-(u/x-c)^2/(2d^2)}}{|x|}=0$ For example, [here is $\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{|x|}$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KKbnc.png).

Comment: @robjohn That's true. Thanks.